# How to turn a matrix into reduced row echelon form by creating a function in R?

Tags: r, for-loop, matrix

For some reason unbeknownst to me, this seems to only go through the outer for loop once, anybody care to help? Here is the code I have thus far:

```
echelon <- function(mat){
    noswaps <- 0
    for(c in 1:dim(mat)[2]){
        if(sum(abs(mat[,c])) != 0){
        pivotcolumn <- mat[,c]
        for(r in 1:dim(mat)[1]){
            if(mat[r,c] != 0){
                pivot <- mat[r,c]
                tmprow <- mat[r,]
                mat[r,] <- mat[(noswaps + 1),]
                mat[(noswaps + 1),] <- tmprow
                mat[(noswaps + 1),] <- mat[(noswaps + 1),]/mat[(noswaps + 1),c]
                if(r > noswaps+1){
                    mat[r,] <- mat[r,] - (mat[r,c]*mat[(noswaps+1),])
                }
                noswaps <- noswaps + 1
                break
            }
        }
        }
    }
    return(mat)
}
```

Comment: What's your example `mat`?

Comment: It isn't. It is running through the outer loop once for each column. It is running the *inner loop* only once because of the `break` statement.

Comment: Generally one would use break only on exception situations. I've also concerns that `noswaps` is being incremented inside the code that is incrementing for both rows and columns.

Answer (score 0):

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16044377/how-to-do-gaussian-elimination-in-r-do-not-use-solve) shows how to do Gauss-Jordan elimination, which should allow you to get to reduced row echelon form.